# Celery chord executed before all tasks are completed

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a bunch of tasks that can be executed simultaneously, but once everything is ready I want to execute a final one. I am using the following code:

```
chunk_tasks = []
for index, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_tasks.append(import_chunk.s(meta.pk))

g = group(chunk_tasks)
chord(g)(import_completed.s(meta.pk, max_lines=max_lines))
```

However it looks like `import_completed` is executed before all tasks are completed. Also the `import_chunk` task looks like:

```
@task(bind=True, ignore_result=IGNORE_RESULTS)
def import_chunk(self, meta_pk):
    try:
        # do some stuff
    except Exception, e:
        if self.max_retries == self.request.retries:
            logger.exception('Unexpected error in import_chunk')
        raise self.retry(countdown=60, max_retries=3)
```

So the question is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Chord is a task that only executes after all of the tasks in a group have finished executing. So, it **needs state of tasks** in  its header for synchronization.

But when you set `ignore_result` to your `task`, the worker **will not store task state** and return values for this task.

This will lead to retrying of task or throwing exception or any malfunction according to your workflow.

So, `chord(add.s(i, i) for i in range(10))(tsum.s()).get()` is perfectly valid and gives result for CASE 1 but it gives some trouble for CASE 2.

**CASE 1:**

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def tsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

**CASE 2:**

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def tsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

So, you have to change `ignore_result` or change the workflow of your tasks.

**From docs:**

*You should avoid using chords as much as possible. Still, the chord is a powerful primitive to have in your toolbox as synchronization is a required step for many parallel algorithms.*

Comment: Yeah, I already stumbled on the issue with ignore_result and it is set to False.